# SQL: Get count of rows returned from a left join

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables, one called **calendars** and the other one called **events**. There can be multiple calendars, and multiple events in a calendar. I want to select every calendar, also getting the number of events in the calendar.

This is what I have :

```
SELECT C.*, COUNT(*) AS events FROM `calendars` AS C 
    LEFT JOIN `events` E ON C.ID=E.calendar 
    GROUP BY C.ID
```

But that doesn't work. *Items with no events still return 1*. **Any ideas?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you´re counting rows, and a calendar that has no events, still have one row of his calendar.

Try this:

```
SUM(case when e.Calendar is null then 0 else 1 end)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and didn't involve sub-selects which is inefficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

You need to use

```
COUNT(E.calendar)
```

On rows with no matches the value of this will be `NULL` and `NULL` values are not counted.

Comment: Wow! this is even simpler than accepted answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
SELECT C.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM events E WHERE E.calendar=C.ID) as NumEvents
FROM calendars C
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT C.*,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM [events] AS E
        WHERE E.calendar = C.ID) AS [events]
FROM [calendars] AS C;
```